# ImportError: No module named _ssl

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ubuntu Maverick w/Python 2.7:

I can't figure out what to do to resolve the following import error:

```
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
   import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

**UPDATE:**
I recompiled the source. I was unable to figure out how to add the --with-ssl option the answers below mention, instead I got this to work by editing the lines regarding SSL in /Modules/Setup.dist.

Comment: Hi...I am facing the same problem...can you please point out what did you edit in Setup.dist

Comment: Once J Cooper not shared his solution, I found one.
http://www.webtop.com.au/blog/compiling-python-with-ssl-support-fedora-10-2009020237

Comment: Since --with-ssl is not recognized anymore I just installed the libssl-dev:

    sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Comment: solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57586800/2083877

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building Python 3.7.1 - SSL module failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543477/building-python-3-7-1-ssl-module-failed)

Comment: I build python with the same configure options on 3 different computer. 2 are good. 3rd one gave this problem. Could not figure out why

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Did you build the Python from source? If so, you need the `--with-ssl` option while building.

Comment: I can't remember if I built from source or not. when do I add the --with-ssl? the ./configure, make, or make install step. when I added this to ./configure it said --with-ssl option was not recognized

Comment: It's an option to `configure`. In general, configuration options, compile-time-switches, and the like, are options to `configure` -- what it actually does is run over many of the source files, making text substitutions (and often creating new header files), before build time.

Comment: I tried to install Python 2.7 and `--with-ssl` does not seem to be recognized any longer...

Comment: Ignore the rest of the advice internet, it's out of date. The extensions build is now controlled by setup.py now. Hack that file, and don't touch Modules/Setup.dist or --with-ssl.

Comment: You don't need `--with-ssl` anymore when building from source as it will look for ssl by default. Make sure you have `openssl-devel` or `libssl-dev` (name depending on your distro) installed and/or hack the `setup.py` file as @ACyclic mentioned to make sure the Python installation is pointing to the ssl headers correctly.

Comment: For Debian Jessie users: as noted on [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88150/how-to-install-python-3-7-with-ssl](this thread) by @Rafa, "Debian 8 Jessie does not provide the Python 3.7 required version of `libssl` in order to compile with SSL support". Either use Python 3.6 or build `openssl` locally for the Python 3.7 build.

Comment: awesome!! on linux 2 aws ami, env all trys result on fail after compile from source code! thankyou very much! after complile with --with-ssl work sucess! pip3 and all module install.

Answer (score 64):

Unrelated to the original question, but because this is the first Google result... I hit this on **Google AppEngine** and had to add:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

to ***app.yaml*** per: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/ssl_support

Please NOTE: This seems to work upto Python version 2.7.9 but not for 2.7.10 or 2.7.11.

Comment: I just tried this and it completely crashed my app to the extent that having commented it out I'm getting a new error and if I leave it in I get ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd

Comment: I've downgraded my version of python from 2.7.11 to 2.7.9 and it now seems to be working

Answer (score 41):

Since --with-ssl is not recognized anymore I just installed the `libssl-dev`.
For debian based systems:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

For CentOS and RHEL

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```

To restart the make first clean up by:

```
make clean
```

Then start again and execute the following commands one after the other:

```
./configure
make
make test
make install
```

For further information on OpenSSL visit the [Ubuntu Help Page on OpenSSL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL#About_OpenSSL).

Comment: If you are on CentOS the command is: `sudo yum install openssl-devel`

Comment: After having openssl-devel installed on my centos, still having the same error message.

Answer (score 15):

If you built Python from source, this is just a matter of dependencies: since you miss OpenSSL lib installed, python silently fails installing the **_ssl** module. You can see it in the final report of the **make** command:

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           _ssl
_tkinter           bsddb185           dbm
dl                 gdbm               imageop
sunaudiodev
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

Installing OpenSSL lib in any of the standard lib paths (`/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`...) should do the trick. Anyway this is how I did :-)

Comment: on a linux system it will work if you install openssl-devel, then reconfigure and recompile.  Remember to recompile or reinstall any services that might need ssl (like tornado) to get ssl.

Comment: on Ubuntu I was able to get the dependencies required to compile the optional modules with `sudo apt-get build-dep python3.4`

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem. I fixed it without rebuilding python, as follows:

1. **Find another server** with the same architecture (i386 or x86_64) and the same python version (example: 2.7.5). Yes, this is the hard part. You can try installing python from sources into another server if you can't find any server with the same python version.
2. In this another server, check if import ssl works. It should work.
3. If it works, then try to **find the _ssl lilbrary** as follows:

   ```
   [root@myserver]# find / -iname _ssl.so
   /usr/local/python27/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
   ```
4. **Copy this file** into the original server. Use the same destination folder:
   /usr/local/python27/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/
5. Double **check owner and permissions**:

   ```
   [root@myserver]# chown root:root _ssl.so
   [root@myserver]# chmod 755 _ssl.so
   ```
6. Now you should be able to import ssl.

This worked for me in a CentOS 6.3 x86_64 environment with python 2.7.3. Also I had python 2.6.6 installed, but with ssl working fine.

Comment: This fixed my problem with linuxbrew python 2.7.10 actually, you don't really need to find another server. Install `linuxbrew` and then install `pyenv`. Build same python release using `pyenv` and copy the _ssl.so over. I also need to remove `_ssl_failed.so` from `~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload` directory.

Comment: A find is very heavy, maybe try: `locate ssl.so` or `locate _ssl.so` first.

Answer (score 3):

The underscore usually means a C module (i.e. DLL), and Python can't find it. Did you build python yourself? If so, you need to include SSL support.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this solution for those who are still facing such issue and cant find the solution.

in my case, I am using

> shared hosting (Cpanel Access) Linux CentOS.

I was facing this issue

```
No module named '_ssl'
```

I tried for all possible solutions but as you know sometimes things don't work for you and in hosting you don't have access to fully root and run queries.
even my hosting provider did for me.. but NO GOOD RESULT.

so how I solved if you are using shared hosting and you have deployed your Django App using

> Setup Python App
>
> You only have to downgrade your Python Version, I downgraded from

```
Python 3.7.3
```

(As Python 3.7 does not have SSL module in it)
To

```
Python 3.6.8
```

through Setup Python App.

Hope it will be helpful for someone with the same issue,

Answer (score 0):

Either install the supplementary packages for python-ssl using your package manager or 
recompile Python using -with-ssl (requires OpenSSL headers/libs installed).

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris 11, I had to modify setup.py to include /opt/csw/include/openssl in the SSL include search path.

Uwe

Answer (score 0):

copy below file from Anaconda3\Library\bin to your exe folder

```
libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libcrypto-1_1-x64.pdb
libpng16.dll
libsodium.dll
libssh2.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll
```