# Module appears in module list but can't be imported

Tags: python

I'm getting an error because the `ssl` module isn't available

If I run `help('modules')` from the python interpreter it is listed there

When I try to import it from the interpreter, I get

```
>>> import ssl

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
```

Comment: Look like this post has your answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128845/importerror-no-module-named-ssl

Comment: Ah, surprised my search didn't catch that one.  I'll try the solution there

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have `openssl` package installed.