# Invoking cqlsh giving error after cassandra installation

Tags: python, cqlsh

Getting Error as below:

```
bin]# ./cqlsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cqlsh", line 134, in <module>
    from cqlshlib import cqlhandling, cql3handling, pylexotron, sslhandling
  File "/u01/cassandra/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/../pylib/cqlshlib/sslhandling.py", line 20, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

Our versions are as below:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
 bin]# python --version
Python 2.6.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be related to this known issue. Try using Python 2.7.x to see if it resolves your issue.

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-322

Another possibility is it could be a Python issue covered here.

[ImportError: No module named _ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128845/importerror-no-module-named-ssl)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Answer, I saw it bit late as I got away with below.

By following the link http://paltman.com/getting-ssl-support-in-python-251/ I was able to enable it.
I Followed below steps.

1. vi Modules/Setup.dist and uncomment as shown below
   204:# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
   205:# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:                             ======>uncomment this line
   206:SSL=/usr/local/ssl                                                                                        ======>uncomment this line
   207:_ssl _ssl.c \                                                                                                 ======>uncomment this line
   208:    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \                        ======>uncomment this line
   209:    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto                                                               ======>uncomment this line
2. cd to Python s/w directory
3. ./config
4. make
5. make install

then invoke cqlsh as below and it worked fine.
cqlsh
Connected to POC at 10.239.133.189:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.5.469 | DSE 4.7.0 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>