# No SSL support included in this python

Tags: python, ssl

I have default python 2.7 on my mac.

I am trying to run the following code using localhost with Google App engine:

```
def sendMail(TO, TEXT):

    fromaddr = 'me@gmail.com'
    toaddrs  = TO
    msg = TEXT

    username = 'me@gmail.com'
    password = 'testpass'

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server.quit()
```

But get the error `No SSL support included in this python`.

This works fine when I just run the python file on its own, separate from everything else.

But when I serve the files using localhost and access it from the website I get the above error.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128845/importerror-no-module-named-ssl

Comment: Did you specify [SSL support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/ssl_support) in your `app.yaml`?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7.9 or a different version?

Comment: I just added SSL Support... now I get the error on `server.starttls()` saying - `permission denied`

Comment: And running live on app engine gives the error - Socket API available once billed on admin console... is there an alternative?