# How to build Python from source on Debian 8.5

Tags: python, linux, debian

I tried to build the latest version of Python (= 3.5.2) from source on my computer (running Debian 8.5). I found tips here:

[SSL and Tkinter not present on source build of Python 3.5.2, Debian Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626755/ssl-and-tkinter-not-present-on-source-build-of-python-3-5-2-debian-linux) ,

https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#compiling-for-debugging

I did the following:

```
 - $ sudo apt-get build-dep python3.5
 - $ sudo apt-get build-dep python3.4 (since python3.5 did not work)
 - Downloaded the tar.xz file from python.org
 - right click -> Extract here.
 - $ cd Python-3.5.2
 - $ ./configure
 - $ ./make
 - $./make test
```

After running `make test` I got (among others):

```
[398/398] test_multiprocessing_fork
386 tests OK.
12 tests skipped:
    test_devpoll test_gdb test_kqueue test_msilib test_ossaudiodev
    test_startfile test_tix test_tk test_ttk_guionly test_winreg
    test_winsound test_zipfile64
```

Now I have got the following question:
 - **How to install this version of Python on Debian 8.5 correctly?**

Comment: `sudo make install` should install a fresh build of Python in the proper place.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I meant that these 12 skipped tests indicate that something went wrong. Did something go wrong? How can I avoid those 12 missing tests?

Comment: Your build should run correctly, but it will be missing a few modules. Those tests are for modules you don't have for some reason or another. Eg, `test_tk` and `test_ttk_guionly` look like they relate to Tkinter, so if you want Tkinter then there's other stuff you need to install. And I _think_ you need to do that & then rebuild your Python, although that might not be necessary.

Comment: (cont) I built Python 3.6 on this rather ancient Debian-derived distro, but that was several months ago and I'm afraid I'm a bit hazy on the details (which is why I'm putting this info into comments instead of a proper answer). However, most of those tests relate to Windows, eg `test_winreg` and `test_winsound`, so you can safely ignore those.

Comment: If you're scared of messing up your system, you could install what you've got to `/opt/python3.x`

Comment: It is nice to hear, that it will run correctly. Nevertheless, I don't understand, why, the modules are missing. I did install python-tk and build-dep python3.4 and thus no modules should be missing. How can I install all the tested modules which belong to Linux? I am sorry, but I can't upvote your comments.

Another question: How do you know, which modules belong to Windows?

Answer (score 1):

These are the debian Dependencies that you need to eliminate all `not built` warnings.

```
sudo apt install libbz2-dev libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev uuid-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev tk-dev libffi-dev
```