# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'

Tags: python

I am calling a python script from another python script,irrespective of the output the python script I am calling I get the following error in `stderr`,I googled but couldn't find anything concrete,am clueless as to why am getting this error?does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 151, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 101, in _get_module_details
    loader = get_loader(mod_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py", line 464, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py", line 474, in find_loader
    for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py", line 430, in iter_importers
    __import__(pkg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 35,
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\charset.py", line 13, in <module>
    import email.base64mime
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\base64mime.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.utils import fix_eols
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    import random
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 49, in <module>
    import hashlib as _hashlib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\hashlib.py", line 138, in <module>
    _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
```

Comment: What minor version of python 2.7 are you using?  This was added in `2.7.9`, is yours less than that?

Comment: Problem with your Python installation? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128845/importerror-no-module-named-ssl

Comment: @donkopotamus - am using 2.7.9,anything else I need to check other than this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `brew cleanup` and after that `brew postinstall python`.

For more info see [this thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/36346)

Comment: how to install `brew`?

Comment: I installed brew `C:>pip install brew
Collecting brew
  Downloading brew-0.1.3.zip (42kB)
    100% |################################| 51kB 1.4MB/s
Installing collected packages: brew
  Running setup.py install for brew ... done
Successfully installed brew-0.1.3`

Comment: even after installing brew ,brew commands are not working..i dont seem to find `brew` executable either,please provide guidance

Comment: Are you working on Windows ? if so - this doesn't apply to you