# python error: asking for ssl module while it is built in

Tags: python, ssl

i have the following error

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 101, in _ssl_wrap_socket
    "SSL certificate validation is not supported without "
CertificateValidationUnsupported: SSL certificate validation is not supported without the ssl module installed. To avoid this error, install the ssl module, or explicity disable validation.
```

i'm running python 2.7.8 32-bit on Windows 7 downloaded from python.org, so I tried `pip install ssl` and it says that it is built in. how to fix this? it is bombing on all scripts interacting with the web. why is it asking me to install something that is built in?

The only think i can think of is... I recently installed `pydrive`, but i uninstalled it and it makes no difference.

Furthermore, i can still `import ssl`.

Comment: Did you build python yourself? This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128845/importerror-no-module-named-ssl

Comment: @jimf weird. I looked at your link, I can actually still `import ssl`. I downloaded the exe file, i don't think i built it myself. I'm a beginner.

Comment: From where did you download the exe file for python setup?

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil python.org, i'm running 2.7.8

Comment: I just upgraded python to 2.7.13 and the issue is gone... what should I do? delete question? or post that as the answer?

Comment: post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issues are gone after I download 2.7.13 (latest version) from python.org and installed it.

Comment: What version of httplib2 are you using?  Downgrading from 0.10.2 to 0.9.2 also seems to do the trick for me.  I opened [an httplib2 issue](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/issues/47) about this.

Comment: it's now 0.10.2 after i installed Python 2.7.13. I don't know what version it was prior to updating python.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably [a bug in httplib2](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/issues/45) which manifests itself on early versions of python 2.7 and which was fixed in httplib2 0.10.3.  Upgrading to the latest Python is always a good idea, but upgrading httplib2 would be sufficient to resolve this issue.