# Building Python 3.7.1 - SSL module failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl

Building Python 3.7 from source runs into following error:

```
Failed to build these modules:
_hashlib              _ssl                                     

Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
LibreSSL 2.6.4 and earlier do not provide the necessary APIs, https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/381
```

I tried so many workarounds from other stackoverflow-questions, but it doesnt work. I build newest OpenSSL and LibreSSL from source. OpenSSL path is: "/usr/local/ssl" with version OpenSSL 1.0.2p.

```
./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl/
(./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/ssl/lib")
make 
make altinstall
```

My system:
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Any ideas?

Comment: Your Ubuntu version looks extremely old. Consider upgrading to 18.04 LTS, it will make many issues like this to simply disappear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named \_ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128845/importerror-no-module-named-ssl)

Comment: @mvp Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and same error, so not the case

Answer (score 50):

I solved it after 3 days only because of [this blog.](https://jameskiefer.com/posts/installing-python-3.7-on-debian-8/) with python 3.7.4 openssl 1.1.0 centOS 6.

here is the summary :

First, some prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

use yum instead of apt-get if using centos linux.

Install ssl 1.0.2 or higher.

```
    cd /usr/src
    curl https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2o.tar.gz | tar xz
    cd openssl-1.0.2o
    ./config shared --prefix=/usr/local/
    sudo make
    sudo make install
```

We will need to pass /usr/src/openssl-1.0.2o into the Python configure script.

```
mkdir lib
cp ./*.{so,so.1.0.0,a,pc} ./lib
```

Now proceed with installing Python:

```
    cd /usr/src
    sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tgz
    sudo tar xzf Python-3.7.0.tgz
    cd Python-3.7.0
    ./configure --with-openssl=/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2o --enable-optimizations
    sudo make
    sudo make altinstall
```

To test it out, run python3.7 and input:

```
import ssl
ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Very useful getting the openssl from source.  I had to make one change, setting the       export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2o/lib    before running the configure command.  This was Ubuntu 14 with Python 3.8.2.  Working, yay !

Comment: Only worked after export LD_LIBRARY as @blissweb mentioned above! Using Debian 8

Comment: Use `rpath` to bake the library path into the executable so that it is not necessary to set the library path each time a Python executable is needed; e.g., pip, virtualenv, etc.  Here is an example:  `LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib" CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -I/usr/local/ssl/include" ./configure --prefix=/home/lawlist/opt/python_3_9_13 --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl`  The key ingredients to a successful Python build and to avoid a `_hashlib` failure when building same were to use the `shared` flag when building `openssl` and use the `--with-openssl` flag when building Python.

Answer (score 18):

## Compiling openssl

> Download your openssl tarball, unzip, and then ensure that the install directory is named `openssl`.

> I placed mine in /usr/local/openssl, so I'll use that in my example.

1. `sudo mv openssl-1.0.2u /usr/local/openssl && cd /usr/local/openssl`
2. `sudo make distclean`
3. `sudo ./config -fPIC -shared`
4. `sudo make && sudo install`

> Now, add the openssl shared library to your PATH.

5. `vim ~/.profile
   Go
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/openssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
   :wq`

## Compiling Python3

> The key here is understanding that the path you define with  `--with-openssl=`  is where Python looks for **/openssl/lib**. You need to give Python the **parent directory** of the openssl directory.

> That means that if you set  `--with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl`  your `make install` will fail even though the `make` logs show that openssl is fine!

> `--enable-optimizations` is irrelevant but recommended - longer make for 10% faster Python code is a good tradeoff.

> `--prefix=` is merely where I'd like python3 to install, if you didn't know.

1. `sudo make distclean`

> Edit your python setup file

2. `vim /{yourpythonsource}/Modules/Setup`

> Uncomment out the following lines and ensure that your SSL variable points to your openssl directory. In mine, it was looking for the directory 'ssl' instead of 'openssl.'

```
<pre><code># Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other </code> 

<pre><code># socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable: </code>

<code>SSL=/usr/local/openssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
-DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
-L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto</code>
```

3. `sudo ./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local --prefix=/opt/python-3.7.1`
4. `sudo make && sudo make install`

Comment: Thank you. Without edit `vim /{yourpythonsource}/Modules/Setup` as you advised i could'nt build python3.8 for raspberry pi 3 "Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"

Comment: Why do you need to add ssl shared library to PATH? Did you mean to add it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: For me the build step for `openssl` was `yum install -y tcl tcl-devel tk tk-devel`
`git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git`
`cd openssl/`
`./config --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/etc/ssl --libdir=lib shared zlib-dynamic -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/ssl -Wl,--enable-new-dtags` as recommended in [wiki.openssl Compilation and Installation ↪ Using RPATHs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Using_RPATHs).

Comment: Very late response, but you're right, I shouldn't have added a ../lib to the $PATH.

Answer (score 14):

While this might not be the best answer, I will share how I solved this problem.

1. First of all, in my case, OpenSSL did not build correctly, as `make test` did return errors (and consequently Python gave this error). This was solved by installing a newer version of Perl and then installing OpenSSL again (configure, make, etc).
2. Use this command before using ./configure

   > export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/openssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
3. At the configure command, include the library:

   > LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/openssl/lib" ./configure (all your preferred options) --with-openssl=/path/to/openssl

   as apparently the option for configure does not convey the message to the C compiler which needs it.

Am not sure whether option 2 and 3 are needed simultaneously, but I did so and it worked.

Comment: Work for me after tried a few other answers. I just didn't use the lib folder in openssl (e.g. just LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/openssl")

Comment: I have tried everything I found on line, and nothing worked until I tried your "LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/openssl/lib" suggestion during ./configure. I already did everything with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and all other suggestions, and none worked until this. Thank you for finally being the one to save my day!

Answer (score 8):

There was ***NO need*** to edit `Modules/Setup` file built python with customed openssl.

I have built `python 3.11.0-rc2` under **Debian 9 stretch** follow the official document:

https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html?highlight=openssl#custom-openssl

> To use your vendor’s OpenSSL configuration and system trust store, locate the directory with `openssl.cnf` file or symlink in `/etc`. On most distribution the file is either in `/etc/ssl` or `/etc/pki/tls`. The directory should also contain a cert.pem file and/or a certs directory.
>
> ```
> $ find /etc/ -name openssl.cnf -printf "%h\n"
> /etc/ssl
> ```
>
> Download, build, and install OpenSSL. Make sure you use `install_sw` and **NOT** `install`. The `install_sw` target does **NOT** override `openssl.cnf`.
>
> ```
> $ curl -O https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-VERSION.tar.gz
> $ tar xzf openssl-VERSION
> $ pushd openssl-VERSION
> $ ./config \
> --prefix=/usr/local/custom-openssl \
> --libdir=lib \
> --openssldir=/etc/ssl
> $ make -j1 depend
> $ make -j8
> $ make install_sw
> $ popd
> ```
>
> Build Python with custom OpenSSL (see the configure `--with-openssl` and `--with-openssl-rpath` options)
>
> ```
> $ pushd python-3.x.x
> $ ./configure -C \
> --with-openssl=/usr/local/custom-openssl \
> --with-openssl-rpath=auto \
> --prefix=/usr/local/python-3.x.x
> $ make -j8
> $ make altinstall
> ```

ssl module check **OK** after installed :

```bash
# /usr/local/python-3.11.0-rc2/bin/python3.11 -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'
OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem with LMDE 5 (running Debian Bullseye) compiling Python 3.10.4. It was fixed by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: Fails on current bullseye, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS / Linux 2 if you install openssl using

```
sudo yum install -y openssl-devel
```

then the library is installed to /usr/local/lib64, and you can configure Python as follows:

```
./configure --enable-shared --with-openssl=/usr/local/lib64
```

there are step-by-step instructions here:  [How to Install Latest (2020) Django to AWS EC2 Linux 2 Instance and Serve w/ Apache Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531052/how-to-install-latest-2020-django-to-aws-ec2-linux-2-instance-and-serve-w-apa)

Comment: Nice one. Your advice solved my SSL problem  on `library/amazonlinux:latest` Docker image.

`yum install -y openssl-devel`

`./configure --enable-shared --with-openssl=/usr/local/lib64 --enable-optimizations`

Comment: Now there is also this one: `yum install -y openssl11-devel` - `Python 3.10` requires `OpenSSL 1.1.1` or newer.

Comment: @TomaszHławiczka https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71951779/python-3-10-building-with-ssl-enabled-with-open-ssl-1-1-1 I could not manage to have it built from 3.10 Can you please let me know, where I am going wrong

Answer (score 2):

Met same issue, looks configure of Python3 can't work well.

If you have installed the latest openssl, make sure the path of OPENSSL_LDFLAGS is correct in Makefile, below is my env case

```
OPENSSL_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib64
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit `setup.py`**

Find the following lines:

```
        system_lib_dirs = ['/lib64', '/usr/lib64', '/lib', '/usr/lib']
    system_include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
```

...and place each folder at the beginning of its respective list.

---

In my case I had to add: `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`:

```
        system_lib_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib', '/lib64', '/usr/lib64', '/lib', '/usr/lib']
    system_include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']
```

Finally: `make distclean && ./configure`

You may want to ensure that `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or what have you) is added to the very end of `/etc/profile` and reboot, as well.

Comment: Yes. I had to combine this `make distclean && ./configure` advice with that of @adam-winter above. Otherwise, gcc warns about "`coverage_mismatch`".

Comment: Didn't solve it for me.
OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021)
Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires a OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer

Answer (score 1):

Execute till download python (3.10.4 is what i tried) from the link below
https://computingforgeeks.com/install-latest-python-on-centos-linux/

Upgrade openssl as documented in https://cloudwafer.com/blog/installing-openssl-on-centos-7/

```
modify $python_home/Modules/Setup
Update the OPENSSL location and uncomment the below lines
--------------------------------------------
OPENSSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -I$(OPENSSL)/include -L$(OPENSSL)/lib \
    -lssl -lcrypto

--------------------------------------------
```

Continue the installation steps from https://computingforgeeks.com/install-latest-python-on-centos-linux/

Hope it helps somebody..
fyi: I was installing this on a centos7 ec2 instance as a part of installing ansible.

Answer (score 1):

My system is an older centos, I am trying to build the latest version stable release of python 3.11.5 (Sep 8, 2023).  After many hours of tracing, I found that python needs > 1.1.1 ssh version (openssl).  After several attemps to install the latest version of ssl (the latest for my OS turned out to be 1.0.x opensssl-devel package). So I have to resort to manual install from tar file of openssl.

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl
make; sudo make install

After install, update system package info:
sudo echo "/usr/local/openssl/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl.conf
For the above command must sudo su to execute the command.
under su do
# echo "/usr/local/openssl/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl.conf

After that do
sudo ldconfig
```

When open ssl is successfully built, it is time to build python3.

./configure --with-ensure`enter code here`pip=inst`en`enter code here`ter code here`all --enable-shared --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl --enable-optimizations --prefix $FOO_HOME

Answer (score 0):

after make and make install openssl, as you can just`openssl version`,
edit python configure
`sudo ./configure --with-openssl-rpath=auto --enable-optimizations`,
and then make and make install python

Answer (score 0):

how i managed to fix it for python 3.11.4: Centos7

**first install openssl:**

```
sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.0.9.tar.gz
tar xvf openssl-3.0.9.tar.gz
cd openssl-3.0.9/
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl
make -j $(nproc)
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
sudo tee /etc/profile.d/openssl.sh<<EOF
export PATH=/usr/local/openssl/bin:\$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl/lib:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
EOF
source /etc/profile.d/openssl.sh
```

**next install python:**

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.4/Python-3.11.4.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.11.4.tgz
cd Python-3.11*/
LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/openssl/lib" ./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl 
make
sudo make altinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Python 3.12/3.10 with openssl on ubuntu 20.04:

https://github.com/davideuler/programming-tips/blob/main/python/install_python_3.12_ubuntu.md

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on an up-to-date Debian Bookworm system with `libssl-dev` installed, and didn't think it should be necessary to build my own openssl. So I ran `bash -x ./configure --prefix=/usr/local > config_err.log 2>&1`. Found out it was using an older openssl installation under /usr/local/. I renamed /usr/local/ssl to /usr/local/ssl.20190819, and added that same suffix to /usr/local/lib/libssl.a, /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a, and /usr/local/include/openssl. The log I made *still* shows it looking for those under /usr/local, but since it can't, obviously it's finding the correct headers and libs under /usr.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution on Mac OS X / Homebrew:

```
brew reinstall openssl
brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force  # careful!
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then download your python tarball and do this:

```
tar xvf Python-3.7.2.tar
cd Python-3.7.2
  ./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" --prefix=$PWD/Python-3.7.2/mybuild --enable-optimizations
```

More detai:

> https://devguide.python.org/setup/#macos-and-os-x

Comment: The brew reinstall was the only thing that worked in my context, thank you!

Comment: You should **not** need `brew link openssl --force`.  It is dangerous and Brew does not symlink openssl for a good reason: "openssl@1.1 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because openssl/libressl is provided by macOS so don't link an incompatible version."