# Cannot install SSL on Python 3.7.1?

Tags: python, ssl

I'll start off with saying I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543477/building-python-3-7-1-ssl-module-failed) already and could not find an answer.

I am on Windows 10, and have been trying to install *pipenv* through powershell.
Only, it returns me the following error:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

So I then downloaded ssl-1.16 from [this website](https://pypi.org/project/ssl/1.16/#files), but then ran into another error:

```
ValueError: This extension should not be used with Python 2.6 or later (already built in), and has not been tested with Python 2.3.4 or earlier.
```

I checked a few forums and still cannot seem to find an answer. So if anyone would know how to come to terms with that, I'd be truly grateful. :)

Thanks

Comment: Why not upgrade to Python 3.7.4? It is very likely this issue is fixed by the latest python version.

Comment: It is `pip3` not `pip`.