# Building Python and OpenSSL from source, but ssl module fails

Tags: python, linux, docker, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to build Python and OpenSSL from source in a container.  Both seem to build correctly, but Python does not successfully create the `_ssl` module.

I've found a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/building-python-with-ssl-support-in-non-standard-location) [guides](https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial/) online that say to un-comment and lines from Python-`3.X.X/Modules/Setup` and add the `--openssldir=/usr/local/ssl` flag to the `./configure` step for OpenSSL.  I do these in my dockerfile.  This has had the effect that, during the `./configure` output for Python, I see the following line.

```
checking for X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host in libssl... yes
```

Yet I receive the following errors:

```
[91m*** WARNING: renaming "_ssl" since importing it failed: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[0m[91m*** WARNING: renaming "_hashlib" since importing it failed: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/_hashlib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[0m
Python build finished successfully!
```

...

```
Following modules built successfully but were removed because they could not be imported:
_hashlib              _ssl                                     


Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
LibreSSL 2.6.4 and earlier do not provide the necessary APIs, https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/381
```

If `./configure` finds `X509...`, why am I still getting the hashlib and ssl errors?

The full Dockerfile, FWIW:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils gcc make zlib1g-dev \
    build-essential libffi-dev checkinstall libsqlite3-dev 
RUN wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz && \
    cd openssl-1.1.1d && \
    ./config -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)' --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl && \
    make && \
    make test && \
    make install
RUN wget -q https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/Python-3.8.2.tgz && \
    tar -xzf Python-3.8.2.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.8.2 && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install
USER jenkins
```

Comment: Hi Jake, why can't you add that line in `Python/Modules/Setup`? You could do a `sed` with in place changes to the file.

Comment: Trying...     `sed -i 's|#       -DUSE_SSL|       -DUSE_SSL| w /dev/stdout' Python-3.8.2/Modules/Setup`.  On my machine it works, on the dockerfile it doesn't.

Comment: And even getting it to work on the Dockerfile gives: ```[91m./python: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by ./python)
[0mgenerate-posix-vars failed
Makefile:592: recipe for target 'pybuilddir.txt' failed
[91mmake: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1
[0m```

Answer (score 9):

The following worked for me on Amazon's EC2, with the default CentOS 7 system.

First, the openssl libraries on CentOS 7 are too old (Python 3.9+ wants openssl 1.1.1+ and the version available is 1.0.x). Install the newer ones:

```
sudo yum install openssl11-devel
```

*Note: since writing this answer, Amazon has end-of-life'd the openssl11-devel package and updated openssl-devel to 3.0.8. 3.0.8 is more than enough for Python, so now you can just do `yum install openssl-devel`.*

Unfortunately, CentOS doesn't actually put the SSL libraries anywhere that Python can find them. With some trial and error, I found that this makes `./configure` happy:

```
export OPENSSL_LIBS=/usr/lib64/libssl.so
./configure \
  --with-openssl=/usr \
  --with-openssl-rpath=/usr/lib64 \
  --enable-optimizations
```

Explanation:

- Python doesn't look in lib64 by default, which is where openssl11 is installed.
- `--with-openssl` takes a path that ./configure appends `include/openssl/ssl.h` to, so make sure that is there for your system!

When you run `./configure`, you're looking for a line near the end of the output like:

```
checking for stdlib extension module _ssl... yes
```

If you see `missing` instead of `yes`, search config.log for openssl, which should give you some guidance about where it's screwing up.

Hopefully this saves someone else the *many hours* I spent figuring this out.

Comment: `sudo yum remove openssl-devel`?  There's absolutely no need to do that.  After installing `openssl11-devel`, use `pkg-config --cflags openssl11` for `CFLAGS` such as header file location, and `pkg-config --libs openssl11` for library link flags, library locations, and the libraries themselves.

Comment: Good point about removing openssl-devel, updated my answer. I haven't used pkg-config before and it's giving me: 

`Package libssl was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'libssl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\n
Package 'libssl', required by 'OpenSSL', not found`

According to `find`, I don't have a libssl.pc. Are you suggesting I write it myself?

Comment: *I don't have a libssl.pc. Are you suggesting I write it myself?*  No. Something must have gone wrong somewhere.  No telling where.

Comment: The above works well for python 3.8 in amazon linux 2 but does not seem to work for python 3.12. Any ideas you have on this?

Comment: Found the answer, the answer lies in the flavour of amazon linux.

If you are using Amazon Linux 2023, then you need to install openssl-devel
If you are using Amazon Linux 2, then you need to install openssl11-devel

Note that Amazon Linux 2 contains both openssl-devel and openssl11-devel

To make my install script generic i did the following which fixed the problem :-)

`if yum info "openssl11-devel" &> /dev/null; then
  sudo yum install -y openssl11-devel
else
  sudo yum install -y openssl-devel
fi`

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> Following modules built successfully but were removed because they could not be imported:
> _hashlib              _ssl                                     
>
> Could not build the ssl module!
> Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
> LibreSSL 2.6.4 and earlier do not provide the necessary APIs, https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/381
> ```

It seems like installation issue when building openssl from source. For build failure on `_ssl` module, try extra options like `--with-openssl`, `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` when configuring Python using the script `./configure`, e.g.

```
./configure  --with-openssl=/PATH/TO/YOUR/OPENSSL_INSTALL_FOLDER/ \
    --enable-optimizations \
    --with-ssl-default-suites=openssl \
    CFLAGS="-I/PATH/TO/YOUR/OPENSSL_INSTALL_FODLER/include" \
    LDFLAGS="-L/PATH/TO/YOUR/OPENSSL_INSTALL_FODLER/"
```

Also try this command `openssl version`, if it reports error like this :

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found
```

that means there is linking problem on your openssl library, I'm not sure if you're on Linux or other system, but for Linux system, you can manually modify the links to openssl library to fix the problem as described [in my answer at here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95719/raspbian-support-for-tls-1-3/105663#105663).

**Reference**

[Building Python 3.7.1 - SSL module failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543477/building-python-3-7-1-ssl-module-failed)

[Python 3.7.0 wont compile with SSL Support 1.1.0](https://bugs.python.org/issue34028#msg358487)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and after 3+ hours of searching THIS is what actually worked:

```
Error: "ssl module is not available" when installing package with pip3
———————————————————-
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by ‘SSLError(“Can’t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.”)’: /simple/pip/

The fix:
———————————————————-
sudo yum install openssl11 openssl11-devel
mkdir /usr/local/openssl11
cd /usr/local/openssl11
ln -s /usr/lib64/openssl11 lib
ln -s /usr/include/openssl11 include
```

The above code creates an alternate path for the latest `openssl11` and symlinks it in a place that matches the folder structure that python expects.

Then proceed with the original steps in the guide
(https://linuxstans.com/how-to-install-python-centos/)

and ./configure like this within your python install folder:

```
./configure -–enable-optimizations -–with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl11
make altinstall
```

the `altinstall` is important so that you don't overwrite the system default python. You'll have to invoke it as `python3.10` from command line thereafter.

I tested this on CentOS 7 and Python-3.10.8.

ref:
https://linuxstans.com/how-to-install-python-centos/?unapproved=4338&moderation-hash=9903c8ebd6634e5bbbad96716e283f8b#comment-4338

Comment: nice ! after painful hours of troubleshooting this, you came to the rescue, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that Jenkins Image comes with some openssl version installed that is not 1.1.1, hence you find X509... in libssl but cant build.

Regarding said config option, you can spin up the container with bash as CMD, copy the config from within the container  to the machine where the Image lies, edit ist and bake your version of the config into the Image.

Comment: Yes, but the point of a Dockerfile is to not need those steps so it can be distributed and reused...

Comment: After you have baked your config into the image, you have a working version of the image, which can be redistributed and reused

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, I do not mean copy the config into the running container. I mean, copy the config OUT OF the running container, edit in on your local machine, and then create a new image which is based on the image in question (FROM image xyz), and use your config in that image (COPY myconfig /path/to/config/in/image)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I can edit the Setup file directly in the container, but apparently that doesn't solve the issue.  `make` still gives me an error: `./python: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: version \`OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by ./python)`.  Any ideas?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, your Dockerfile works for me