# How to compile python in linux using an existing openssl library?

Tags: python, openssl

I would like to compile Python 3.10 with openssl.

I'm having difficulties locating the already installed openssl library in linux and supplying it to the `--with-openssl` option. How do I locate the existing library and pass it to this option, thus compiling Python 3.10 with the existing openssl library?

There is a very nice and comprehensive explanation in the offical documentation: https://devguide.python.org/setup/#compile-and-build

There is a great explanation on StackOverflow already how to compile with openssl: [Building Python 3.7.1 - SSL module failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543477/building-python-3-7-1-ssl-module-failed/57586800#57586800)

However, in this explanation openssl is downloaded and compiled. Since openssl is already available on my machine, I would prefer to use the existing openssl.

This is a snippet from the explanation:

```
cd Python-3.7.0
    ./configure --with-openssl=/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2o --enable-optimizations
    sudo make
    sudo make altinstall
```

I'm using a current linux mint and openssl version 1.1.1f is installed.

`openssl version` returns `OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`

Thank you very much and have a nice day.