# Trouble using pyinstaller "No module named '_ssl'"

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pyinstaller

I trying to use pyinstaller to generate my binary file in python.
In my program I use flask_socketio. I try to generate my binary file with that command:

```
pyinstaller server_websocket.py
```

Here is the command's result:

```
328 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.9
328 INFO: Python: 3.6.9
329 INFO: Platform: Linux-4.15.0-166-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
330 INFO: wrote /home/marc/test_program/server_websocket.spec
332 INFO: UPX is not available.
333 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/marc/test_program/']
581 INFO: checking Analysis
581 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
581 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
582 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
598 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3693 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
3791 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3836 INFO: Analyzing /home/marc/test_program/server_websocket.py
6057 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-distutils.py'.
6064 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/usr/lib/python3.6'
16867 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-site.py'.
16914 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/fake-modules'
24225 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-six.moves.py'.
41921 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.GObject from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.GObject.py'.
41931 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.Gtk from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.Gtk.py'.
45927 INFO: Processing module hooks...
45927 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-parso.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
45940 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
45949 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
47336 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbconvert.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
47349 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-bcrypt.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
47350 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
47620 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
47626 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytest.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
48727 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
49125 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-notebook.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
50493 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
50510 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
50517 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
50542 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nacl.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
50565 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
51036 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtGui.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
52928 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
53001 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
53017 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'test'
53018 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
53340 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtCore.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
53377 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
53384 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
54944 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
55004 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtPrintSupport.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
55173 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
55174 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
55182 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
55223 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'f2py'
55233 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-wcwidth.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
55236 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
55237 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
55260 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
55278 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
109418 WARNING: Hidden import "PyQt5.sip" not found!
109418 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
111268 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-win32com.py'.
111308 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
111309 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
111316 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
111797 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
111827 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
111842 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-shelve.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
111864 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
111886 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
112396 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
114911 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": added
115387 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": added
115634 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx'
117599 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": added
-c:12: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg backend was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
118508 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
-c:12: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4cairo backend was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
118858 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": added
119267 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
119749 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": added
119980 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": ignored
    No module named 'tkinter'
120188 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    No module named 'tkinter'
120779 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
122212 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": added
122621 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": added
123105 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": added
123372 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
123686 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": added
124178 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
124589 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
124944 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
125226 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
125623 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
127819 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.Gio from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.Gio.py'.
127829 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.GLib from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.GLib.py'.
127837 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.Gdk from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.Gdk.py'.
128329 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtSvg.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
128840 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
128985 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
128986 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtWidgets.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
129097 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zope.interface.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
129106 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
129167 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.GObject.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
129810 WARNING: Hidden import "gi._gobject" not found!
129810 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
129818 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.Gtk.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
132583 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.xlib from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.xlib.py'.
132596 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.Atk from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.Atk.py'.
132605 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtNetwork.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
132890 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
132905 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
133068 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
133105 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.Gdk.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
133814 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.cairo from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.cairo.py'.
133815 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.Pango from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.Pango.py'.
133816 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.GdkPixbuf from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.GdkPixbuf.py'.
133816 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
133825 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
136472 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
136478 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.GdkPixbuf.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
136929 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.GModule from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repository.GModule.py'.
136930 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
136938 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.GLib.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
137192 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
137197 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.Gio.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
137391 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.Atk.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
137518 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.xlib.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
137625 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
137645 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
137651 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.GModule.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
137765 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.cairo.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
137884 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.Pango.py' from '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
138199 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
138698 WARNING: Library user32 required via ctypes not found
138927 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
138949 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_subprocess.py'
138950 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
138957 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_inspect.py'
138958 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
138962 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_traitlets.py'
138968 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
138970 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_gtk.py'
138971 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_gdkpixbuf.py'
138972 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_glib.py'
138973 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_gio.py'
138973 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_gi.py'
138974 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pyside2.py'
138975 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
138976 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
139014 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
147845 WARNING: Cannot find libz-a147dcb0.so.1.2.3 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libpng16-bedcb7ea.so.16.37.0)
147865 WARNING: Cannot find libfreetype-6ad068c6.so.6.17.4 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libharfbuzz-ba5e3cba.so.0.20800.0)
147878 WARNING: Cannot find libpng16-bedcb7ea.so.16.37.0 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libfreetype-6ad068c6.so.6.17.4)
147878 WARNING: Cannot find libz-a147dcb0.so.1.2.3 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libfreetype-6ad068c6.so.6.17.4)
147905 WARNING: Cannot find libwebp-305e7d94.so.7.1.1 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libwebpmux-1d369df0.so.3.0.6)
147919 WARNING: Cannot find libwebp-305e7d94.so.7.1.1 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libwebpdemux-2a7a19d5.so.2.0.7)
148209 WARNING: Cannot find libgfortran-ed201abd.so.3.0.0 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-8a0c371f.3.13.so)
148369 WARNING: Cannot find libXau-312dbc56.so.6.0.0 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libxcb-2dfad6c3.so.1.1.0)
148369 WARNING: Cannot find libXdmcp-e15573e7.so.6.0.0 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libxcb-2dfad6c3.so.1.1.0)
148394 WARNING: Cannot find liblzma-99449165.so.5.2.5 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libtiff-d147fec3.so.5.6.0)
148395 WARNING: Cannot find libjpeg-ba7bf5af.so.9.4.0 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libtiff-d147fec3.so.5.6.0)
148395 WARNING: Cannot find libz-a147dcb0.so.1.2.3 (needed by /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libtiff-d147fec3.so.5.6.0)
148442 INFO: Looking for eggs
148442 INFO: Using Python library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
148473 INFO: Warnings written to /home/marc/test_program/build/server_websocket/warn-server_websocket.txt
148662 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /home/marc/test_program/build/server_websocket/xref-server_websocket.html
149628 INFO: checking PYZ
149628 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
149628 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/marc/test_program/build/server_websocket/PYZ-00.pyz
151869 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/marc/test_program/build/server_websocket/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
151911 INFO: checking PKG
151911 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
151911 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) server_websocket.pkg
152031 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) server_websocket.pkg completed successfully.
152033 INFO: Bootloader /home/marc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit-intel/run
152033 INFO: checking EXE
152033 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
152033 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
152033 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to /home/marc/test_program/build/server_websocket/server_websocket
152040 INFO: Appending PKG archive to custom ELF section in EXE
152099 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
152159 INFO: checking COLLECT
152159 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
152159 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
500517 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Then I move the binary file in build/test_program/server_websocket to dist/test_program/server_websocket and I run the binary file server_websocket. I get that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server_websocket.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "socketio/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "socketio/client.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "engineio/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "engineio/client.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "ssl.py", line 101, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
[28442] Failed to execute script 'server_websocket' due to unhandled exception!
```

I work on ubuntu 18.04 with Flask-SocketIO==4.3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named \_ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128845/importerror-no-module-named-ssl)

Comment: I already try this but none of these solution work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the solution.
For people who facing the same trouble:

Here is the command I use for create the binary file:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import _ssl --hidden-import engineio.async_gevent --hidden-import engineio.async_eventlet  --hidden-import ssl ./server_websocket.py -y
```

I also need to modify the socketIO call:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app,     async_mode='gevent')
```

And import that:

```
from engineio.async_drivers import gevent
```