# I'm using ESP32 and have problem with flashing

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, debian-packaging, esp-idf-sys

I'm using debian12 system in that i want to run and debug my hello world example given by ESP32-S2-kaluga-1 manual I have downloaded esp-idf extension in visual studio and while setting up OpenOCD I'm facing issue as below

I tried these commands

```
ftd@debian:~/Documents/esp_work/esp-idf$ . $HOME//Documents/esp_work//esp-idf/export.sh
Setting IDF_PATH to '/home/ftd/Documents/esp_work/esp-idf'
Detecting the Python interpreter
Checking "python3" ...
Python 3.11.5
"python3" has been detected
Checking Python compatibility
Checking other ESP-IDF version.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ftd/Documents/esp_work/esp-idf/tools/idf_tools.py", line 43, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 100, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
```

Comment: At first glance, this seems to be a python installation problem unrelated to ESP flashing. Do any of the answers given here solve it?  [ImportError: No module named \_ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128845/importerror-no-module-named-ssl)